# Find keys in dictionary and use a part of the key as a variable

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

Given I have a collection of keys in a dictionary:

```
dictionary=({"key[0]":1, "bar[0]":1, "key[2]":2, "key[4]":3, "foo[1]":3, "bar[3]":2, "dummy":42})
```

I want to search for all the keys matching regex pattern `key\[([0-9]+)\]` and process them capturing the first (and only) regex pattern group in the key.
In other words - I want to select only the keys `"key[someIntValue]"` and do an operation on them while also having the someIntValue value available as a variable (or in some way that I could refer to it).

Using pseudocode I want to express:

```
        for <all the keys matching "key[someIntValue]"> in dictionary
            function(someIntValue)
```

Do I need to use regex for that or is there some other way? What would be the best code solution for such problem? Does the answer differ between Python 2 and Python 3?

Answer (score 3):

Since your keys should always be the exact same, you can compare the strings instead of using regex.

```py
dictionary={"key[0]":1, "bar[0]":1, "key[2]":2, "key[4]":3, "foo[1]":3, "bar[3]":2, "dummy":42}
for key in dictionary.keys():
    if key[:4] == 'key[' and key[-1] == ']' and key[4:-1].isdigit():
        keydigit = int(key[4:-1])
        print(keydigit)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex and an appropriate capturing group:

```
import re

pat = re.compile("^key\[(\d+)\]$")  # \d+: one or more digits, (): capt. group
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    m = pat.match(k)
    if m:
        i = int(m.group(1))  # this is someIntValue
        # do stuff with i, k, v
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension to make a new dictionary which maps the keys to the digit in them if they match your pattern:

```
import re
pattern = "^key\[(\d+)\]$"
matches = [re.search(pattern, key) for key in dictionary.keys()]
new_dictionary = {match.group(0): int(match.group(1)) for match in matches if match is not None}
```

Note that `match.group(0)` is the key and `match.group(1)` is the digit. Also note that `match` is none if it does not match your pattern.

The above will return a new dictionary which maps the keys to their integer value if they meet your specifications. In your example, it returns `{'key[0]': 0, 'key[2]': 2, 'key[4]': 4}`. Now you can do

```
for key, digit in new_dictionary.items():
    ...
```